# Base64 Data Type

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

I am looking into different ways I can access base64 DataType file using Python 2.7
**Below are Details**
LogFile
Type
    base64
Description
    Encoded file data in .csv format.The EventType field defines the schema for this data.

Eventhough the file data is encoded in .csv, I am planning to ingest into ELK stack.

Comment: any reason why you are still using Python 2.7? It is not bad but kind of deprecated .

Comment: Also you are able to read csv data?

Comment: Any reason why you're using base64? Does it really need to be encrypted/encoded? Base64 isn't really that secure so if it's sensitive you might want to look into more secure forms of encoding inside python.

Comment: You are correct. I using API calls to access information which is Base64 datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data as a string and then decode it via

```
base64.decodestring(your_string)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html for details